# Evaluating a logic circuit expression

Tags: equation

My test says the answer is c) **A** OR **B**.

To me it looks like: Q = **AB** + (**A**+**B**)

What am I doing wrong?

Which of the following is a logical expression that is equivalent to the logic circuit shown below?

[image]

Answer is c.

a) **A** AND **B**
b) **A** AND (**A** OR **B**)
c) **A** OR **B**
d) **B** AND (**A** OR **B**)

Comment: Make a truth table for AB, A+B and AB+(A+B) and see if a term can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not doing the algebra, just looking at the diagram:

1. The first OR gate will be true if A or B is true.
2. The second OR
   gate will be true if the first OR gate is true.
3. Therefore if A OR B is true, then the output is true.

Continuing on with the diagram analysis:

4. If A and B are true then the first OR gate will also be true. (goto 3)
5. If A and B are true then the AND gate will be true (goto 3)
6. If A and B are false then the first OR gate will be false and the AND gate will be false, therefore the second OR gate will be false.

Comment: So the AND gate doesn't even matter here?

Comment: @Justin I added more analysis, which shows (A OR B) when both are true and false. Though not sure it's required as a proof.  Steps 1-3 solves it.

Comment: @tymac Nope.  The AND gate is superfluous in this case.

Comment: I think the problem for me are the answers. I don't even know what the answers mean in the context of the logic circuit. I only know how to reach the Boolean equation `Q = AB + (A+B)`.

Comment: When I write an equation for that circuit I always get `Q = AB + (A+B)`. So I would like to go from that equation to the answer `A OR B`.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose AB = 1. This implies that A = 1 and B = 1. What is the value of A + B in this case?

Also, be aware that some people naturally use "or" to mean one or the other, but not both. That is *not* the definition used in scientific contexts like this, though. Here both inputs can be true and the "or" will still also be true. Only pointing this out in case you are using the former definition.

Comment: The value of A + B would then be 1 in the case you described. 1 OR 1 = 1. But how does this apply to the logic circuit? There's an AND gate as well. When I write an equation for that circuit I always get `Q = AB + (A+B)`. So I would like to go from that equation to the answer `A OR B`.

Comment: @tymac Here is one way doing it algebraically, AB+A+B -> A(B+1)+B -> A(1)+B -> A+B, the other one is visually if you make the truth table which I think would help you much more. The key point is that AB and A+B **overlaps**, you can't make something that is twice true to be even more true, it's still just true. A third way of doing it is via Karnaugh diagrams which you will learn in a couple of weeks/month's - So it's okay to be confused now, everything will eventually click.